# How to reduce the time spent on testing?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, tdd, functional-testing

I just looked back through the project that nearly finished recently and found a very serious problem. I spent most of bank time on testing the code, reproducing the different situations "may" cause code errors.

Do you have any idea or experience to share on how to reduce the time spent on testing, so that makes the development much more smoothly?

I tried follow the concept of test-driven for all my code , but I found it really hard to achieve this,  really need some help from the senior guys here.

Thanks

Re: all

Thanks for the answers above here, initially my question was how to reduce the time on general testing, but now, the problem is down to how to write the effecient automate test code.

I will try to improve my skills on how to write the test suit to cut down this part of time.

However, I still really struggle with how to reduce the time I spent on reproduce the errors , for instance, A standard blog project will be easy to reproduce the situations may cause the errors but a complicate bespoke internal system may "never" can be tested throught out easily, is it worthy ? Do you have any idea on how to build a test plan on this kind of project ?

Thanks for the further answers still.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Test driven design is not about testing (quality assurance).  It has been poorly named from the outset.

It's about having machine runnable assumptions and specifications of program behavior and is done by programmers during programming to ensure that assumptions are explicit.

Since those tasks have to be done at some point in the product lifecycle, it's simply a shift of the work.  Whether it's more or less efficient is a debate for another time.

What you refer to I would not call testing.  Having strong TDD does mean that the testing phase does not have to be relied upon as heavily for errors which would be caught long before they reach a test build (as they are with experience programmers with a good spec and responsive stakeholders in a non-TDD environment).

If you think the upfront tests (runnable spec) is a serious problem, I guess it comes down to how much work the relative stages of development are expected to cost in time and money?

Comment: Very honest answer and answered my question.

Answer (score 3):

I think I understand.  Above the developer-test level, you have the customer test level, and it sounds like, at that level, you are finding a lot of bugs.

For every bug you find, you have to stop, take your testing hat off, put your reproduction hat on, and figure out a precise reproduction strategy.  Then you have to document the bug, perhaps put it in a bug-tracking system.  Then you have to put the testing hat on.  In the mean time, you've lost whatever setup you were working on and lost track of where you were on whatever test plan you were following.

Now - if that didn't have to happen - if you had far few bugs - you could zip along right through testing, right?

It's doubtful that GUI-driving test automation will help with this problem.  You'll spend a great amount of time recording and maintaining the tests, and those regression tests will take a fair amount of time to return the investment.  Initially, you'll go much slower with GUI-Driving customer-facing tests.

So (I submit) that what might really help is higher /initial/ code quality coming out of development activities.    Micro-tests -- also called developer-tests or test-driven-development in the original sense - might really help with that.   Another thing that can help is pair programming.

Assuming you can't grab someone else to pair, I'd spend an hour looking at your bug tracking system.  I would look at the past 100 defects and try to categorize them into root causes. "Training issue" is not a cause, but "off by one error" might be.

Once you have them categorized and counted, put them in a spreadsheet and sort.  Whatever root cause occurs the most often is the root cause you prevent first.  If you really want to get fancy, multiply the root cause by some number that is the pain amount it causes. (Example: If in those 100 bugs you have 30 typos on menus, which as easy to fix, and 10 hard-to-reproduce javascript errors, you may want to fix the javascript issue first.)

This assumes you can apply some magical 'fix' to each of those root causes, but it's worth a shot.  For example: Transparent icons in IE6 may be because IE6 can not easily process .png files.  So have a version control trigger that rejects .gif's on checkin and the issue is fixed.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

The Subversion team has developed some [pretty good test routines](http://subversion.tigris.org/hacking.html#write-test-cases-first), by automating the whole process.

I've begun using this process myself, for example by writing tests *before* implementing the new features. It works very well, and generates consistent testing through the whole programming process.

SQLite also have a decent test system with some [very good documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/testing.html) about how it's done.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience with test driven development, the time saving comes well after you have written out the tests, or at least after you have written the base test cases.  The key thing being here is that you actually have to write our your automated tests.  The way your phrased your question leads me to believe you weren't actually writing automated tests.  After you have your tests written you can easily go back later and update the tests to cover bugs they didn't previously find (for better regression testing) and you can easily and relatively quickly refactor your code with the ease of mind that the code will still work as expected after you have substantially changed it.

Comment: thanks for your answer and yes, I didn't wrote the test suits to cover 100% of the codes . So that test by click mouse and view in browser still is the first choice to test the code I wrote in the last projects.

Answer (score 2):

You wrote:

> "Thanks for the answers above here,
>   initially my question was how to
>   reduce the time on general testing,
>   but now, the problem is down to how to
>   write the efficient automate test
>   code."

One method that has been proven in multiple empirical studies to work extremely well to maximize testing efficiency is combinatorial testing.  In this approach, a tester will identify WHAT KINDS of things should be tested (and input it into a simple tool) and the tool will identify HOW to test the application.  Specifically, the tool will generate test cases that specify what combinations of test conditions should be executed in which test script and the order that each test script should be executed in.

In the [August, 2009 IEEE Computer article I co-wrote with Dr. Rick Kuhn, Dr. Raghu Kacker, and Dr. Jeff Lei](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/SNS/acts/documents/kuhn-kacker-lei-hunter09.pdf), for example, we highlight a 10 project study I led where one group of testers used their standard test design methods and a second group of testers, testing the same application, used a combinatorial test case generator to identify test cases for them.  The teams using the combinatorial test case generator found, on average, more than twice as many defects per tester hour.  That is strong evidence for efficiency.  In addition, the combinatorial testers found 13% more defects overall.  That is strong evidence for quality/thoroughness.

Those results are not unusual.  Additional information about this approach can be found at http://www.combinatorialtesting.com/clear-introductions-1 and our tool overview [here](http://hexawise.com/Hexawise_Introduction.pdf/).  It contains screen shots and and explanation of how of our the tool makes testing more efficient by identifying a subset of tests that maximize coverage.

Also free version of our Hexawise test case generator can be found at [www.hexawise.com/users/new](http://www.hexawise.com/users/new)

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing inherently wrong with spending a lot of time testing if you are testing *productively*.  Keep in mind, test-driven development means writing the (mostly automated) tests first (this can legitimately take a long time if you write a thorough test suite).  Running the tests shouldn't take much time.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your problem is you are not doing automatic testing.  Using automated unit and integration tests can greatly reduce the amount of time you spend testing.

Answer (score 1):

First, it's good that you recognise that you need help -- now go and find some :)

The idea is to use the tests to help you think about what the code should do, they're part of your design time.

You should also think about the total cost of ownership of the code. What is the cost of a bug making it through to production rather than being fixed first? If you're in a bank, are there serious implications about getting the numbers wrong? Sometimes, the right stuff just takes time.

Answer (score 0):

One of the hardest things about any project of significant size is designing the underlying archetecture, and the API.  All of this is exposed at the level of unit tests.  If you're writing your tests first, then that aspect of design happens when your coding your tests, rather than the program logic.  This is compounded by added effort of making code testable.  Once you've got your tests, the program logic is usually quite obvious.

That being said, there seem to be some interesting [automatic](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/Pex/) test builders on the horizon.